# Como adicionar botao em um painel?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso adicionar um botão no meu flowLayoutPanel quando clicado no botão de adicionar ( btnAdicionar ). Meu Panel se chama `mainPanel`

OBS : Eu consegui adicionar, mas preciso que adicione do tamanho dos outros botões.

CÓDIGO

```
namespace SlidingPanel
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private readonly Button[] _todosBotoes;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        //Passo 1

        _todosBotoes = mainPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
    }

    private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(panel1.Width == 350)
        {    

            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Width = 65;

        }

    }

    private void btnVoltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(panel1.Width == 65)
        {

            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Width = 350;


        }

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (panel1.Width == 350)
        {
            btnVoltar.Hide();

        }
        else
        {

            btnVoltar.Show();
        }

    }



    private void txtBuscarJogo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Passo 2.1
        var controles = _todosBotoes.Where(btnArcheAge => (btnArcheAge.Tag as String ?? btnArcheAge.Text).ContainsIgnoreCase(txtBuscarJogo.Text)).ToArray();
        //Passo 2.2
        mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        //Passo 2.3
        mainPanel.Controls.AddRange(controles);
    }

    private void lblAmigos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Tag = i;


            mainPanel.Controls.Add(button);
        }
     }

}
}

namespace MyMethod
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
        {
            return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O array de buttons, que é a fonte dos buttons, está readyonly, mas basta vc adicionar mais um elemento a ele, e preencher novamente o panel

Comment: Ok eu consegui ajustar o tamanho, mas tem como ele herdar as características, cor, tamanho de outro button criado?

Comment: Não precisa desse for de 0 a 1, rsrs, pra copiar as propriedades: Button.Size = _todosBotoes[0].Size;

Comment: Nem deu certo. É pra apagar todo o código dentro do btn e colocar só esse seu?

Comment: Ah já entendi, consegui, mas e a cor ? como eu pego daquele botão ja criado? por exemplo a cor é AliceBlue dos botões

Comment: button.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue; fiz isso, até deu certo mass, sera que tem outra forma? kk

Comment: então, uma pergunta: Já que tem essa opção de adicionar, não terias que armazenar em algum lugar para quando fechar a aplicação e ao abrir novamente não ter perdido essa informação ?

Comment: seria bom sim, mas por enquanto só to aprendendo umas funções kk

Comment: @DárioSabaini Tua intenção é apenas criar um novo botão com o mesmo padrão visual dos outros?

Comment: Para você colocar a cor do botão da mesma cor de outro, é só fazer da seguinte maneira: `button.BackColor = buttonbase.BackColor;` no caso troque o buttonbase, pelo nome do botão do qual você quer pegar a cor.